# Run deploy automatically when branch receives MR on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, cicd

I want to run automatically my deploy job on Gitlab when my branch receives a merge by merge request. How can I do this?

```
deploy-tests:
  tags:
    - aws-sdk
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - stage
  cache: {}
  script:
    - cd ngapp
    - call npm ci
    - call npm run-script i18n
    - call npm run-script lint
    - call build.bat tests
    - copy .htaccess dist
    - copy Web.config dist
    - deploy.bat tests
```

Comment: You want your pipeline to start after the merge has finalized. Or when a merge request happens?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your pipeline to be executed when it receives an MR.
You need to pass the keyword `merge_requests` at your `only` clause. (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs)
Change

```
deploy-tests:
  tags:
    - aws-sdk
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - stage
  cache: {}
  script:
    - cd ngapp
    ...
```

To

```
deploy-tests:
  tags:
    - aws-sdk
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - stage
  cache: {}
  script:
    - cd ngapp
    ...
```